# Kotlin - Why isn't there a "Progression" interface like in the case of "ClosedRange"?

Tags: kotlin

Kotlin has defined:

```
class CharRange : CharProgression, ClosedRange<Char>
```

but looking at `CharProgression`:

```
open class CharProgression : Iterable<Char>
```

there is no `Progression` interface. It directly implements `Iterable`.

Why doesn't Kotlin define a `Progression` interface as it has done with `ClosedRange`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe someone from JetBrains will correct me, but I would assume that the reason lies here:

```
// Auto-generated file. DO NOT EDIT!

import kotlin.internal.getProgressionLastElement
```

All this class hierarchy, including internal `CharProgressionIterator` is being auto-generated. Hence, being both internal and generated, it doesn't make much sense to have an interface nothing but the generated code would use.